# AS3 gotoAndStop causes object to remove itself

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I have a student who is working on a Tower Defense game in AS3 and has an issue that has stumped me. He is using hitTestObject to change the direction that a movieClip is moving. The movieClip has its own timeline with frames for the different directions that the object is facing and a linked .as file with the code for the behavior of the object.

When he calls gotoAndStop to change the internal frame of the movieClip, the removed event is triggered, but the object stays on the screen and no longer moves.

All of my searches find answers about removing objects, but I have not seen anything about preventing an object from removing itself.

The following code is a loop triggered by an ENTER_FRAME event in the .as class file for the movieClip object:

```
private function eFrame(event:Event):void
    {

        if (_root.isPaused == false)
        {
            //MOVING THE ENEMY
            this.x +=  speed * xDir;
            this.y -=  speed * yDir;
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                _root.currency +=  4;

                this.parent.removeChild(this);
            }
            if (this.x > 770)
            {
                this.parent.removeChild(this);
                _root.health -=  10;
                _root.gotHit = true;
            }
            //checking if touching any invisible markers
            for (var i:int=0; i<_root.upHolder.numChildren; i++)
            {
                //the process is very similar to the main guy's testing with other elements
                var upMarker:DisplayObject = _root.upHolder.getChildAt(i);
                if (hitTestObject(upMarker))
                {
                    yDir = 1;
                    xDir = 0;
                    this.gotoAndStop(3);


                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<_root.downHolder.numChildren; i++)
            {
                //the process is very similar to the main guy's testing with other elements
                var downMarker:DisplayObject = _root.downHolder.getChildAt(i);
                if (hitTestObject(downMarker))
                {
                    yDir = -1;
                    xDir = 0;
                    this.gotoAndStop(7);

                }
            }

            for (i=0; i<_root.rightHolder.numChildren; i++)
            {
                //the process is very similar to the main guy's testing with other elements
                var rightMarker:DisplayObject = _root.rightHolder.getChildAt(i);
                if (hitTestObject(rightMarker))
                {
                    yDir = 0;
                    xDir = 1;
                    this.gotoAndStop(6);
                }
            }
            for (i=0; i<_root.leftHolder.numChildren; i++)
            {
                //the process is very similar to the main guy's testing with other elements
                var leftMarker:DisplayObject = _root.leftHolder.getChildAt(i);
                if (hitTestObject(leftMarker))
                {
                    yDir = 0;
                    xDir = -1;
                    this.gotoAndStop(2);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    private function remove(event:Event):void
    {
        trace("remove");
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);
        _root.enemiesLeft -=  1;

    }
}
```

When the gotoAndStop line executes, the frame of the movieClip changes and then the code jumps directly to a function that is triggered by the REMOVED event.

Does anyone have an idea why the REMOVED event might be triggered by this code?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REMOVED Event is triggered by anything that is removed from the stage inside the MovieClip or Sprite that is containing it, if I'm not mistaken. And especially with MovieClips that have animation, things get removed and added everytime, for instance if some part of the animation ends on the timeline, or at keyframes.

Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE is dispatched only when the container itself is removed from stage. Maybe that's causing your confusion? I can't see from your code example exactly what event type you're listening for.

Comment: Thank you. Changing my Event Listener from REMOVED to REMOVED_FROM_STAGE solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you adding the remove-listener?

Without more information, I would guess that you are listening to a clip inside an animation, and that it's not there on all frames (or, maybe even more likely - that the instance is being swapped out for another, identical one, by flash pro. This can happen depending on in what order you added keyframes, the alignment of the moon and fluctuations in the ionosphere. It's easiest fixed by simply removing all key-frames and then re-creating them. And then never using flash pro for anything ever again.)